# Specifying Environment variables in JCL

Tags: environment-variables, zos, jcl

Physical DSN name specified together with the DD name in JCL is the usual way of handling files in ZOS.

But we can also specify a variable DD name in FILE CONTROL and set the DSN in program using SETENV.
 e.g.  [How to set environment variables and dynamic file declaration](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21046577)

Is there any way to set environment variables using JCLs and access the external variable in program using GETENV(similar to EXPORT in linux or SET in windows)?

Comment: If you are asking what I think you are asking, then No. If you are not asking what I think you are asking, then clarify the question please. Remember, you know what you mean, we only know if you can described illustrate it accurately. What I think you are asking is "can I change a JCL Symbol using SETENV (or anything else). If that **is** your question, the answer is No. The entire JCL stream is "converted/interpreted" (CI) as part of the preparation for processing, not part of processing. By the time your JOB starts, the JCL does not even exist anymore. So you can't change anything in it.

Comment: It was a typo, I meant GETENV usage in program,

Comment: Ah. So your question is, can I use GETENV to get the resolved value of a JCL symbol into my program, instead of the already-discussed us of PARM? Can you get some more detail into the question, including what using GETENV would give you as a particular approach, please?

Comment: The link you provided has three methods for "doing things" to allow dynamic allocation of DSNs. Can up explain what you are trying to do, and where those methods fail for you?

Comment: I was looking for a facility like STDENV available to EPXBATCH utility. It would enable one to access a variable value in the program. A typical usage would be defining name of a output dataset(PDS).  Program would use the dynamic allocation of out put using PDS name with member name, e.g. MY.DSN(member)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the _CEE_ENVFILE environment variable to specify a DD or a data set name for setting environment variables. I assume using GETENV which is a C LE runtime function is just as simple of using SETENV.

```
PARM=('ENVAR("_CEE_ENVFILE=DD:STDENV")/')
```

Comment: But i suspect if GETENV works properly in COBOL programs, Should it require a C wrapper as it returns a character pointer?

Comment: Check out CEEENV which is a much better interface for getting/setting environment variables from COBOL https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ceea300/clcenv.htm.

Comment: Zos version in our  site is much older, therefore CEEENV is not available. But a C wrapper to GETENV ( with 2 parameters) would work properly.

Comment: No need for a C wrapper. Just make sure you get the linkage conventions right for ILC and watch out for the null terminated strings. Introducing a wrapper is an extra layer of complexity that you can do without. You might even find that you don't have a C compiler at your site.

Comment: Enterprise COBOL can CALL C functions. CEEENV is provided for this specific purpose. If you need a null-terminated constant, if is a Z'-literal, and for data "null-terminated" means make sure there is room for an extra byte following (the terminator) your data. Ensure that the first non-data byte is "low-values"/binary zero. Pointers are not an issue. COBOL's CALL .... BY REFRENCE is automatically pointers, and any actual pointers there is SET with ADDRESS OF and the definition of USAGE POINTER items.

Comment: I could invoke getenv directly from COBOL, corresponding to the returning value (char * in c) a pointer variable is used in COBOL. Then address of a linkage section variable(X(n)) is assigned to it.

Comment: _CEE_ENVFILE environment variable did not work with COBOL main program. It works with C main program.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CEEGTJS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=services-ceegtjsretrieves-value-exported-jcl-symbol) Language Environment (LE) Callable Service to retrieve the value of an [EXPORT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=reference-export-statement)ed JCL symbol.

I recommend anyone programming on z/OS become familiar with [Language Environment (LE) Callable Services](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=guide-language-environment-callable-services).  LE Callable Services are part of z/OS and available to all applications written in C, C++, COBOL, PL/I, and Assembler, subject to [documented restrictions](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=services-using-language-environment-callable).

Comment: Zos version that I am using is too old, so this solution is  not suitable for me. thanks.